# How to get a specific item value from list group row with Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a list group with many rows each row has more than two data each item has an  `id` , I wish if i click a such row i can get a custom value, but the way I am using gives me all row's values. If try to change `this` to items `id` it does effect only on first row (position 0 of listGrou). please help me,
[image: The way a list looks like], [image: browser CONSOLE RESULT after click second row]

Html and php code :

```
<div  id="listid">  
    <ul class="list-group p-5 col-sm-8 offset-2" id="content">
<?php 
    while ($registered = mysql_fetch_array($query_student)) {
?>
        <li class="list-group-item  list-group-item-action Divlistid" >
            <a href="#">
                <span id="name">
                    <h4><b>
                    <?php echo $registered['firstname']; ?>
                    </b></h4>
                </span>
                <span id="gender">
                <?php echo $registered['gender']; ?>
                </span>
        </li>

<?php 
    } 
?>
    </ul>  
</div>
```

Jquery code which is not getting a custom item but all row's items:

```
$(".list-group-item").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id')
    var text = $(this).text();
    console.log(id)
    console.log(text)
})
```

Comment: This is not a PHP problem, get rid of the PHP code and provide a sample of the resulting HTML instead.

Comment: Hi, sorry but it is not clear what you want to get from the list, can you show an example of a good result please

Comment: You don't have `id` attribute on elements with class `.list-group-item`, and there's more, your `span` elements have a constant `id` in loop, therefore you will have multiple duplicate id's

Comment: @RiggsFolly , I put a screen shoots you can see the results

Comment: @darklightcode, of course I will have many doublicate `id's` but I think as the above example works, there is a way to extract specific element to all of them , is what I need.

Comment: No, `id` must be unique on the page for them to work properly. Think of then a an `id` column in the database, if 2 id's have the value 1 then it would not work would it

Comment: @AlexisMUGWANEZA i suggest you target element index instead, `$(this).index()`, based on it's position you can wrap an `if` around it.

Comment: Now I have sensibly formatted the code do you see what you have missed out of the HTML to make it well formed?

Comment: @RiggsFolly someone's gotta do the dirty work. Have a vote +1

Comment: I am unclear what you actually want the code snippet to output vs what it is currently outputting.

Answer (score 0):

Target your `li's` by index:

```
$(".list-group-item").('click',function(){

     var liIndex = $(this).index();
     if( liIndex === 0 ){ // i'm the first li from .list-group }

     // target last - logical
     if( liIndex === $(this).parent().children('.list-group-item').length -1 ){ // i'm the last li from .list-group }

    // target last - hardcoded
     if( liIndex === $('.list-group .list-group-item').length -1 ){ // i'm the last li from .list-group }

})
```

Comment: ,Thanks , but mostly an issue of mine is not to get indexes of list-group , but to get  specific value `on each row of a list-group` whenever a row is clicked

Answer (score 0):

You can not have multiple elements in your DOM with the same ids. You can try to concatenate these ids with the loop counter for example and target elements with jquery using 'class' attribute.